# String index out of range when reading data

Tags: python

For this problem, I have a separate txt file which contains a list of values down below:

```
Years+1900 Populationx106
0 1650
10 1750
20 1860
30 2070
40 2300
50 2560
60 3040
70 3710
80 4450
90 5280
100 6080    
110 6870
```

For the problem I'm working on, I'm supposed to obtain that file and path name to then use to do calculations on with some functions I created. I have finished the functions I need to do, however I'm having an issue running it because I believe when doing the function it reads the "Years+1900 Populationx106" part first instead of the numbers below it.

Here's the code for my functions:

Input: year
Output: estimate of population for that year

```
def pop(year):
    return 1436.53*((1.01395)**year)
```

```
# Input: data
# Return: the average error as per equation 18.
def error(data):
    error=0
    for i in data:
        error +=(abs(i[1]-pop(i[0]))/i[1])
    return 100*error/12
```

Here is the code I created to retrieve the data from my separate txt file:

```
def get_data(path,name):
    with open("Assignment7/pop.txt", "r") as path:
        path = open("Assignment7/pop.txt", "r")
        name = path.read()
        return name
```

The error I'm receiving is for the part below. It is an index error and it says the string index is out of range. I believe this is because it is reading the first part of the data in the pop.txt, how can I remove te first line in the pop.txt so that it only reads the numerical values I have?

```
        error +=(abs(i[1]-pop(i[0]))/i[1])
```

I have tried changing the index values already, however it still says that my string index is out of range.

Comment: How are you calling error?

Comment: What does this “data” input actually look like after you’ve processed it to pass into your error function?

Comment: @ChaseMcDougall I'm not sure actually, I just ran it by itself and nothing popped up in my terminal. Is there another way I can check this?

Comment: The Python Print statement (https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp) is a very useful tool for debugging things like this. Something like `print(data)` will show you what exactly you are processing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are correct and passing the first line of your text file to your function is breaking it.

You can "throw away" the first line of the text file by reading it as a single line (but doing nothing with it) and then reading the data you actually want like this..

```
def get_data(path,name):
  with open("Assignment7/pop.txt", "r") as path:
    path = open("Assignment7/pop.txt", "r")
    header=path.readline() #Read "Header line", but don't use it
    name = path.read() #Read subsequent lines as the data you want
  return name
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you’ve simply read the entire file as one string. Therefore each element, i, is a single character and has no dimensionality. You’ll need to either parse the file by the new line character to split it into by line (and likely again to get it the two separate columns).

[Python String Split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) will be useful for the that.

You’re correct that the first line will pose issues, but this can be removed by using a `path.readline()` call as Richard said.